# How can i seperate 12.879671, 77.583937 into 12.879671856686713 and 77.58393798322277 as a two different string

Tags: android, string, textview, android-edittext, location

I am working on a project where i am copying location from google map. There i am getting location like this format 12.879671856686713, 77.58393798322277. I want to separate this latitude and longitude in two different edit text

Answer (score 2):

If that is a single string, you can use split string functions of Kotlin or Java which ever you are using.

In kotlin

```
val latAndLon =  "12.879671856686713, 77.58393798322277".split(", ")
val latitude = latAndLon[0]
val longitude = latAndLon[1]
```

In Java

```
String[] latAndLon = "12.879671856686713, 77.58393798322277".split(", ");
String latitude = latAndLon[0];
String longitude = latAndLon[1];
```